# How to use the createIndexes () function from mongoose to write a text match search method?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, nestjs

My task is to write an API in which there will be a text match search method,
across the entire database, including nested objects. And for that I need an index.
When I worked with typegoose, I used an index decorator. But there is no such decorator in mongoose,
therefore, I use the createIndexes () function, which takes options from CreateIndexesOptions.
The most optimal option, as I think fieldsAsRaw. But as a result, I get an empty array.

```
@Schema()
export class TopPageModel {

 @Prop({ enum: TopLevelCategory })
  firstCategory: TopLevelCategory;

  @Prop({ required: true })
  secondCategory: string;

  @Prop({ required: true, unique: true })
  alias: string;

  @Prop({text: true})
  title: string;

  @Prop({ required: true })
  category: string;

  @Prop(HhData)
  hh?: HhData;

  @Prop([TopPageAdvantages] )
  advantages: [TopPageAdvantages];

  @Prop({ text: true})
  seoText: string;

  @Prop({ required: true })
  tagsTitle: string;

  @Prop([String])
  tags: [string];
}

export const TopPageSchemaFactory = SchemaFactory.createForClass(TopPageModel);


                                     TopPageService

    async findByText(text: string) {
        const index =  this.topPageModel.createIndexes(
            {fieldsAsRaw:{title:text, seoText:text }}
      )
      if(!index){
        console.log("Error")
      } 
      const search = this.topPageModel.find({index});
      return search;  
 }


                                  TopPageController
  @Get('textSeatch/:text')
  async findByText(@Param('text') text: string) {
    return this.topPageService.findByText(text);
  }
```